# Exporting test data result in Hudson

Tags: hudson, hudson-plugins, hudson-api

Does anybody know of an easy way to export test results in Hudson?  We have some integration tests that are failing intermittently and our executives would like an excel-style report of the failures, in order to do this we need direct access to the backing data or perhaps the ability to export to csv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing specifics of your build languages or integration testing frameworks,  I suggest that you write a build task that exports your testing output into some common location, on or off the server.

You could also publish the testing output as an artifact from the job, and have an external tool pull the data from the permalink on the job's page.

Furthermore, you could create a Hudson job that runs automation to transform the testing output into the Excel format that your executives desire. For example, if you are using JUnit, you could write a script to get the test's output XML from the build, parse it, and output into an excel format. This Hudson job might run nightly or could be triggered after the build of the main project.